# How to identify same user using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have

- channel_id(id of the browser from which the user is coming to my website) (not null)
- cart_id(cart_id of the user can be null)
- email(email of user can be null).

The Definition of user id

- when channels are the same then it is one user
- when cart_ids  are the same then it is one user
- when emails are the same then it is one user
  How can I identify that a user is coming from various channels and from various emails but with same cart id is one user?
  Example:

  | Channel_id | cart_id | Email | User |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 2 | 245 | j@g.com | 2 |
  | 2 |  | j@k.com | 2 |
  | 2 | 123 |  | 2 |
  | 6 | 243 |  | 6 |
  | 7 | 566 |  | 7 |
  | 8 | 566 |  | 7 |
  | 9 |  | k@k.com | 6 |
  | 10 | 243 | k@k.com | 6 |
  | 11 | 243 |  | 6 |

Comment: So... what's the question??

Comment: How can I identify that a user is coming from various channels and from various emails but with same chart id is one user?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Posing images of technical information like sample data or results, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images. (And I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: It's unclear whether the question you've posted is what you actually mean but I believe it comes down to finding `DISTINCT` rows, which you may or may not have (if you don't then the answer is it's not possible). I've posted an answer which explains the concept and shows why the sample data and question you've asked might be misleading.

Comment: @Andy please check the example table. This is the sample of my data and Column user says want I want as result.

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear, but in the comments it's suggested the question is

> How can I identify that a user is coming from various channels and from various emails but with same chart id is one user?

That is your answer. If one user is from **various** channels, and **various** emails... then you cannot identify an individual by this alone because none of that data is unique. Consider

```
channel | email
--------|--------
CH1     | a@b.com
--------|--------
CH2     | a@b.com
--------|--------
CH3     | c@d.com
--------|--------
```

Based on what you've said this could be:

- One individual, coming from 2 separate channels (CH1, CH2) with 1 email address (a@b.com)
- One individual, coming from 3 channels (CH1, CH2, CH3) with 2 different email addresses (a@b.com and c@d.com)
- Two different individuals (a@b.com and c@d.com) coming from  2 and 1 channels respectively.
- Three different individuals where 2 people happen to have used the same email address (either deliberately or accidentally).

Unless there are clear rules on what "a user" (an individual) is, you cannot work it out from this data.

You then said "with the **same** chart (presumably meaning cart) ID". This is the only distinct data so is your only means to tie records to an individual user.

```
channel | email   | cart_id
--------|-------- |--------
CH1     | a@b.com | CRT_1
--------|---------|--------
CH2     | a@b.com | CRT_1
--------|---------|--------
CH3     | c@d.com | CRT_2
--------|---------|--------
```

In this case the only possibility is:

- a@b.com is one user, coming from 2 channels, with a single unique cart ID (CRT_1)
- c@d.com is another user, coming from 1 channel, with a single unique cart ID (CRT_2)

The only reason for the extra row for a@b.com is if they have multiple sessions. But the `SELECT DISTINCT(cart_id) ...` is the only way to tell which are the individual users.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `SELECT DISTINCT` will give you distinct _rows_.

Comment: But what if CH1 CR_2 too If we have one more row like CH1 c@d.com CRT_2 then ?

Comment: @VipulRathore refer to the comment *Unless there are clear rules on what "a user" (an individual) is, you cannot work it out*. You need to have *something* which is distinct and allows you to identify multiple rows as one individual person. If you don't have that then the answer is simple: you can't do it.